# Error in shapiro_test function in a dplyr pipeline sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline

I'm struggling with following dplyr pipeline:

```
library(rstatix)
normality_table <- df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(., -c(A, C, D),'s') %>%
  group_by(D, s) %>% 
  shapiro_test(value)
```

After which, I've been obtaing the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `data`.
i `data = map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
x Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `variable` is not found.
```

Actually that is quite strange because if I just run the part of pipeline with no ruuning the shapiro_test() function, it correctly turns back this

```
     normality_table <- df %>%
    +   tidyr::pivot_longer(., -c(A, C, D),'s') %>%
    +   print()
   # A tibble: 900 x 5
       A C     D               s     value
   <int> <chr> <fct>           <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 E      988.
 2     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 F      995.
 3     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 G     1012.
 4     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 H      988.
 5     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 I      994.
 6     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 J     1008.
 7     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 K      994.
 8     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 L      999.
 9     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 M     1010.
10     1 Maybe new_value_for_8 N     1000.
```

Confirming that the variable 'value' exists in that datasets. Is there anyone that knows the problems that is going on?

Here the dataset I'm working on:

```
    > dput(head(df, 10))
structure(list(A = 1:10, C = c("Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", 
"Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe"), D = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("new_value_for_8", 
"new_value_for_6", "new_value_for_4"), class = "factor"), E = c(988.368784828308, 
988.856158671407, 996.004085290553, 999.685844324618, 1000.23888564896, 
1005.03749946898, 999.786378084971, 997.039675082569, 998.028313183065, 
997.168905747014), F = c(994.834756009939, 994.468875098246, 
1000.62150212342, 1002.23100741241, 1003.96990710863, 1007.75899775608, 
998.699806256246, 996.401009591011, 998.076594704249, 1002.19344184533
), G = c(1011.88022669726, 1012.10534266625, 1012.9554415821, 
1015.09810043606, 1015.40462298842, 1016.67103699915, 1003.13771453335, 
999.9107434841, 1002.15365554737, 1013.67789244066), H = c(988.221495702721, 
990.850727928741, 992.418094914622, 995.984841639886, 993.398346143465, 
997.971380355398, 1004.4672957051, 1002.54036572775, 1002.2292388993, 
999.116379988893), I = c(994.035709684742, 994.890815628412, 
997.18267770374, 998.564426335124, 996.851278420874, 1000.16039368502, 
1003.52155765272, 1002.1043798945, 1002.7069399281, 1005.49897156208
), J = c(1008.23981597718, 1009.51261484649, 1009.42367409926, 
1005.06332653216, 1005.02619159395, 1009.07903916629, 1007.56089165218, 
1005.49719893791, 1004.91476855238, 1013.03209535721), K = c(994.327042030287, 
995.608170991922, 997.033470393412, 1000.15918365269, 998.216388150646, 
1001.97377908784, 1003.17401220482, 1001.60211665164, 1002.27932356239, 
1002.41479226363), L = c(999.225538268699, 999.349990537239, 
1001.14010250645, 1001.51403741206, 1000.25571835554, 1003.76051565494, 
1002.74763442988, 1001.09116707486, 1003.29833843754, 1006.55857216695
), M = c(1009.99385579756, 1011.12126521731, 1010.6989716872, 
1003.7899021821, 1004.59413830322, 1008.52123662618, 1006.34418311104, 
1004.1077131243, 1004.94124365003, 1011.89121961563), N = c(999.801263745036, 
996.838989582336, 1000.89599227983, 1003.11042068113, 1002.27800090558, 
1003.83846437952, 1000.70169995102, 1001.75290674649, 998.660833714301, 
1006.69246804854), O = c(1002.96437294923, 997.870867692911, 
1002.94619035116, 1003.44844607015, 1003.02403433836, 1004.70457675466, 
999.880559826981, 1000.66826545719, 999.59436981446, 1007.32640154038
), P = c(1006.28027312932, 1005.24535230967, 1007.68162285336, 
1001.08242973466, 1002.99896314, 1005.36085942954, 1001.22060069797, 
1000.43007709819, 1000.47666761108, 1008.73650967215)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You are trying to calculate shapiro statistics on very small dataset per group. `group_by(COND)` should go without any error.

Comment: Mmm..actually it didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xx <- structure(list(ID = c("01", "01", "01", "04", "04", "04"), GR = c("RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP"), SES = c("V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V"), COND = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC"), class = "factor"), P3FCz = c(-11.6312151716924, 
-11.1438413285935, -3.99591470944713, -0.314155675382471, 0.238885648959708, 
5.03749946898385), P3Cz = c(-5.16524399006139, -5.53112490175437, 
0.621502123415388, 2.23100741241039, 3.96990710862955, 7.75899775608441
), P3Pz = c(11.8802266972569, 12.1053426662461, 12.955441582096, 
15.0981004360619, 15.4046229884164, 16.671036999147), LPPearlyFCz = c(-11.7785042972793, 
-9.14927207125904, -7.58190508537766, -4.01515836011381, -6.60165385653499, 
-2.02861964460179), LPPearlyCz = c(-5.96429031525769, -5.10918437158799, 
-2.81732229625975, -1.43557366487622, -3.14872157912645, 0.160393685024631
), LPPearlyPz = c(8.23981597718437, 9.51261484648731, 9.42367409925817, 
5.06332653216481, 5.02619159395405, 9.07903916629231), LPP1FCz = c(-5.67295796971287, 
-4.3918290080777, -2.96652960658775, 0.159183652691071, -1.78361184935376, 
1.97377908783621), LPP1Cz = c(-0.774461731301161, -0.650009462761383, 
1.14010250644923, 1.51403741206392, 0.25571835554024, 3.76051565494304
), LPP1Pz = c(9.99385579756163, 11.1212652173052, 10.6989716871958, 
3.7899021820967, 4.59413830322224, 8.52123662617732), LPP2FCz = c(-0.198736254963744, 
-3.16101041766438, 0.895992279831378, 3.11042068112836, 2.27800090558473, 
3.83846437952292), LPP2Cz = c(2.96437294922766, -2.12913230708907, 
2.94619035115619, 3.44844607014521, 3.02403433835637, 4.7045767546583
), LPP2Pz = c(6.28027312932027, 5.24535230966772, 7.68162285335806, 
1.08242973465635, 2.99896314000211, 5.36085942954182), time = c("t1", 
"t2", "t3", "t1", "t2", "t3")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

You can only calculate shapiro test statistic on sample size > 2 observations. Grouping by `COND` variable should work, though:

```
xx %>% 
tidyr::pivot_longer(., -c(ID, GR, SES, COND, time),'signals')%>%
group_by(COND) %>% 
summarise(s = rstatix::shapiro_test(value))
```